# How to update approver comments in opportunity object

Tags: apex, soql, community, approval-process

My requirement is to copy the approver comments in the Opportunity Level Field

When the approver approves the record with comments.I have to update in opportunity level.
Is there a  way to achieve this?

Comment: The comments are are stored in ProcessInstanceStep Objec.
and SObject type does not allow triggers: ProcessInstanceStep>
So, I believe it is not possible

Comment: Even i proposed to my sales team.This is not a better one because if a user can  submit approval for multiple times.It is difficult to handle multiple comments.But i'm working on this thanks once again.@Pavan tej

Comment: Batch Apex can solve this problem, but obviously that wont be real time.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is way to do this. Here is how:

1) Add action in your approval process to update 'Dummy' field

2) This will kick off Opportunity trigger

3) In Opportunity trigger query ProcessInstanceStep object which hold the comments data

4) Copy that data Opportunity Level Field

5) Make sure you handle recursion and bulkification in trigger.